# Postgres| Check constraint on inet field to restrict range of ip net masks

Tags: postgresql

Question is regarding check constraint on inet.

I have a following table:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table administration_ipblacklist
(
    ip          inet                     not null
        constraint administration_ipblacklist_pkey
            primary key,
    record_time timestamp with time zone not null,
    stretch     interval                 not null
        constraint stretch_positive_check
            check (stretch > '00:00:00'::interval)
);
```

Where `ip` column can hold `ip4` and `ip6` networks, for example:

```
# ip4 network
59.9.52.0/24

#ip6 network
2001:db8::1000/122
```

I want to make check constraint that would restrict net mask from `24` to `32` bit for `ip4` networks and `120` to `128` for `ip6` networks.

Examples:

```
# ip4 network
59.9.52.0/24 -allowed
59.9.52.0/29 -allowed
59.9.52.0/21 -not allowed, < 24


#ip6 network
2001:db8::1000/122 -allowed
2001:db8::1000/127 -allowed
2001:db8::1000/100 -not allowed, < 120
```

Is it any straightforward non-hacky way to do so?

Thank you...

Comment: I guess a check constraint would be using [masklen](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `family()` and `masklen()` functions to accomplish this:

```
create table ipcheck (ip inet not null);
CREATE TABLE
alter table ipcheck add constraint netmask_bits_check check 
  (   (family(ip) = 4 and masklen(ip) between 24 and 32) 
   or (family(ip) = 6 and masklen(ip) between 120 and 128)); 
ALTER TABLE

insert into ipcheck values ('59.9.52.0/24');
INSERT 0 1

insert into ipcheck values ('59.9.52.0/29');
INSERT 0 1

insert into ipcheck values ('59.9.52.0/21');
ERROR:  new row for relation "ipcheck" violates check constraint "netmask_bits_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (59.9.52.0/21).

insert into ipcheck values ('2001:db8::1000/122');
INSERT 0 1

insert into ipcheck values ('2001:db8::1000/127');
INSERT 0 1

insert into ipcheck values ('2001:db8::1000/100');
ERROR:  new row for relation "ipcheck" violates check constraint "netmask_bits_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2001:db8::1000/100).
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks a lot!